# Open connection while another connection is open

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i need to call a function that do some query while another connection is opened and its doing a transaction.

Ok i get this is weird, here some code:

Main part:

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    Dim command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
    Dim transaction As SqlTransaction
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("myTransaction")
    command.Connection = connection
    command.Transaction = transaction
    command.CommandText = sSQL
    Try
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim functionResult As String = myFunction(param1, param2)
        If functionResult <> "" Then
            'error! i need to rollback the first query done here!
            transaction.Rollback()
        else
            transaction.Commit()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        transaction.Rollback()
    End Try
    End If
End Using
```

*myFunction* do lot of stuff, and a lot of querys. Every query needs to reopen connection (without transaction this time) but everytime i try to execute the first query inside my function i got timeout error from database (after 30 seconds).

I know i can do this work "copy-pasting" all the myFunction code inside that already opened connection and using the already opened connection, but i use that function more than once and i don't want to mess up my code.

How can i solve this?

edit for more information:
that was an already reduced version of the code i'm using, but here a reduced version on what "myFunction" do:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "my connection string"
Dim queryString As String = "SELECT id FROM foo WHERE param1 = @myValue"
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
Try
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()
        command.CommandText = queryString
        command.Parameters.Add("@myValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 10
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(ds, "randomName")
        If ds.Tables("randomName").Rows.Count < 0 Then
            'error!
            connection.Close()
            Return "error"
        End If
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    Return "Database error - " & ex.Message
End Try
```

The code execution (even in debug) freeze on the `adapter.Fill(ds, "randomName")` command for 30 seconds, after that i get a timout error

Comment: well, one connection is the one on the first piece of code, the second connection is opened from "myFunction" that is called while the first connection is still open!

Comment: Yep, you are right, I missed this part - but then realized afterwards, thanks for your fast response. Why not do `transaction.Commit()` after `ExecuteNonQuery`? What's in `sSQL`? What I mean is that your transaction is actually over at that point, because SELECT is usually not transactional, only UPDATES/INSERTS are. So it looks like these code pieces can go **in sequence**, instead of being nested in each other.

Comment: because the "myFunction" do some SELECT and some UPDATE, if it fails i need to rollback the first query done in main code. Still, i can't get to the myFunction's UPDATE because it fails before, on the first SELECT

Comment: Speaking about myFunction, I can see it doing SELECTs (via Fill), where are the UPDATEs? I understand that, what I am trying to say is that you probably should reconsider your query sequence. You usually don't SELECT in the middle of UPDATE.

Comment: it's a reduced version, the full "myFunction" is 160 lines of code! :) i do the UPDATE using the same syntax as the SELECT i posted, just with different SQL

Comment: Well I don't need the whole code as you may imagine. Just need to know the sequence of queries on a higher level, i.e. which tables are SELECTed, UPDATEd and INSERTed into.

Comment: i think we're going a little far from the original question :( but myFunction do a SELECT and a simple UPDATE on a single table (no joins) and the UPDATE in the first query (yes, sSQL contains an UPDATE) still work and the same table but different records

Comment: If you don't want to be going far, see my answer. It fully explains why you are experiencing the issue, with reference to docs and possible solutions (changing isolation level). I was going to provide you with a **solution** (while keeping the isolation level at default), but I need more information from you for that.

Comment: thank you for all the help and the support :) i'm checking your answer as correct but for solve my problem i'm going to do a manual rollback (with an entire new query and new connection) after the myFunction call. Thank you for all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use as many connections as you want, just make sure they don't interfere with each other. SQL server is very diligent about preserving data integrity, so if one uncommitted transaction conflicts with another uncommitted transaction, you get a deadlock.

You may want to play with [transaction isolation level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx), default is READ COMMITTED for SQL server, try to set it to READ UNCOMMITTED. Please read the docs to be aware of the consequences.

From the above link:

> In SQL Server, you can also minimize locking contention while protecting transactions from dirty reads of uncommitted data modifications using either:
>
> - The READ COMMITTED isolation level with the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option set to ON.
> - The SNAPSHOT isolation level.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i can't edit any parameter on the SQL Server and "myFunction" doesn't use transaction, it fail on its first "SELECT"

Comment: @HypeZ: Can you be more specific on what exactly is happening in your code? I am assuming it fails when you are doing processing through more than 1 connection, is that correct? If so, assume two connections and provide a reduced test case/example for your issue. Please do not include details here and update your original question instead.